# Is there any function in Django that tests if a field instance of a model is primary key?

Tags: python, django, model

In Django, is there a way (function) to test if a model field is primary key (`pk`)?

For instance, my model is:

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is there a function to test for name being primary key?

Comment: Why would you need to know (and not know already)? What's the use case?

Comment: It's related to another problem. To be able to treat a case of translation of primary key field in `django-modeltranslation` package. Reference in [link] (https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/issues/144),  comment on 31 Oct 2016 by yerihyo. My related question in [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779674/setting-django-model-primary-key-field-for-translation-with-django-modeltranslat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get_field` from the [model meta api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field), then check the `primary_key` attribute, which will be `True` for primary keys.

```
field_name = 'name'
field = MyModel._meta.get_field(field_name)
field.primary_key
```

Comment: For get_field method, there's another parameter 'many_to_many', what if the filed is a m2m field?

Comment: @Alasdair, just please correct second line of code. I think you was meant `field = MyModel._meta.get_field(field_name)`, right?

Comment: I don't understand your first comment - [`get_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field) takes a single argument `field_name`, so I'm not sure what you're asking about m2m fields.